# For cursor joining tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

could you help me out, can't figure out this one, I get the following error message:

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 32:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 3, column 8:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 32:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'V_CUR_SPOKENLANG' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 11, column 11:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Tried to find solution in Oracle Forum and 
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00942.php

Also tried to do it by this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

But got basically the same results.

I have access to both these tables with `SELECT`.

The code I'm having problems with:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_spokenlang IS
   SELECT country_id, country_name, language_id 
      FROM wf_countries c, wf_spoken_langugages sl
         WHERE c.country_id = sl.country_id;            
BEGIN
FOR v_cur_spokenlang IN cur_spokenlang
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cur_spokenlang.country_name || ' ' ||   
                           v_cur_spokenlang.country_id || ' ' || 
                           v_cur_spokenlang.language_id);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you run the select for the cursor itself without a problem? Are you missing a schema prefix perhaps?

Comment: I can access both of the tables seperatly with SELECT. I think it might be a joining error, tried with the schema prefixes infront on table names in the FROM clause, no luck either.

Comment: Please look into my answer, check for the privileges to that table, if it is through a role.

Comment: Let's simplify the problem. Change the select to a single column in a single table and validate that you can select on that table, then try the other one. If both of those work you can focus on a join problem.

Comment: Hey guys!
Thank you all, especially Maheswaran Ravisankar the "c." prefix was missing from the SELECT statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the tables you mentioned is `INVALID` (May be `invalid schema` you run or no `PUBLIC SYNONYM`).

Also noticing that the `country_id` is left ambiguous . Needs to be `c.country_id`.

Please make sure, you have the privileges to the user directly and not via any `ROLES`. Because, to be access via a PL/SQL the user id needs to have direct `SELECT` privileges over the tables.!

Answer (score 1):

> If you are on windows Use SQLTools IDE.  http://www.sqltools.net/
>
> Whenever there is an error.The Cursor directly jump to the point where
>   the error is.